# Missing files and assembly

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I found some problems with my Farm.  The first problem I noticed was when I tried to make a new workflow in Designer.  I got several errors; most interestingly, Microsoft.SharePoint is missing.  I got the following errors:

> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that
>   does not exist.  Some actions will not be available.  The assembly
>   strong name is Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
>
> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that
>   does not exist.  Some actions will not be available.  The assembly
>   strong name is Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Actions, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
>
> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that
>   does not exist.  Some actions will not be available.  The assembly
>   strong name is Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.

After running this PowerShell command, "stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus", I got this error:

> System.Bad ImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. This
>   assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime
>   and cannot be loaded.

It seems like I am miss some DLLs.  I have run the repair tool and I have uninstalled and reinstalled SharePoint, but I get the same errors.  Any idea on how to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you did an in-place upgrade. In-place upgrades are not supported. If so, I'd recommend installing SharePoint 2013 on another server and then pulling the databases from that farm over to the brand new SharePoint 2013 server after you created a farm.

See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617150.aspx

Comment: My predecessor says the VM was an in-place upgrade.