# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, custom-workflow

We have a custom workflow which works with Sharepoint 2010 and when we are migrating SP 2010 to SP 2013 we are getting the below error 
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Can anyone suggest us how to resolve this issue without modifying existing workflow dll's
Appreciate you quick response

Answer (score 0):

If you have done an in-place upgrade, you should know that In-place upgrades are not supported on Windows-based Azure VMs.

See the reference below:

[Performing an in-place system upgrade is not supported on Windows-based Azure VMs.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014997/performing-an-in-place-system-upgrade-is-not-supported-on-windows-base)

You can refer to some posts with similar issue here:

[Missing files and assembly.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178631/missing-files-and-assembly)

[Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406037/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)